# Trying to use reactiveFileReader with AWS S3 files to update Shiny app

Tags: r, amazon-s3, shiny

I'm trying to build a Shiny App that pulls dynamically updated data from an S3 bucket. I can currently pull data, but it doesn't update itself. I've been through the documentation for `reactiveFileReader` and [examples](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/reactive-poll-and-file-reader.html), but can't figure it out? Help extremely appreciated!!!

Code below:

```
getFile<-function(){
  my_bucket <- 'globalrss'
  file <- paste0(as.character(getwd()),"/tmp")
  r <- aws.s3::save_object("bodytype.csv", my_bucket, file=file)
}

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  fileReaderData <- reactiveFileReader(500, session, getFile(), readLines)

  output$fileReaderText <- renderText({
    text <- fileReaderData()
    length(text) <- 14
    text[is.na(text)] <- ""
    paste(text, collapse = '\n')
  })
})`
```

Comment: maybe this solution is helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63673007/r-reactivefilereader-reading-from-aws-s3-bucket/65109304#65109304

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to put the file reading part of your code in an `observer`. Maybe something like this:

```
shiny::shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

getFile<-function(){
  my_bucket <- 'globalrss'
  file <- paste0(as.character(getwd()),"/tmp")
  r <- aws.s3::save_object("bodytype.csv", my_bucket, file=file)
}

theFile<- getFile() # do this once, just so you have the data right away

# Now setup an observer that surrounds invalidate later and the file read code

observe({

shiny::invalidateLater(millis=30000, session=session) # run every 30 seconds
theFile<<- getFile() # get the contents of the s3 bucket, replace data
cat(file=stderr(), "updating data", "\n") # have this report actions to the console, can be removed later

})



output$fileReaderText <- renderText({
    text <- theFile
    length(text) <- 14
    text[is.na(text)] <- ""
    paste(text, collapse = '\n')
  })


    })
```

Hopefully this gets you closer to what you want. Good luck. Cheers, nate